# Question involving basic limits.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)= \frac{(x^2-y)y}{x^4}$, if $0<y<x^2$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=0$ over any line which pass through origin, but   $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) \neq 0$.

Actually, I'm trying to understand this question. Because if I get a line passing throughing the origin $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\gamma(t) = (t,\alpha t)$, then

$$\lim_{t \to 0} f(\gamma(t)) = \frac{\alpha t^3 - \alpha^2 t^2}{t^4} = \infty \neq 0$$.

Furthermore, How can I show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0 $??? I usually find some bounded function and another going to zero, but I didn't see that in this case.

Comment: By definition $y \leq 0$ and $y \geq t^2$ implies $f(\gamma(t)) =0$, but what about $0<y<x^2$ ?? I didn't get you

Comment: doesn't exists $t$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you approach the origin along the parabola $y=x^2/2$, $f(x,y)$ is constantly equal to one fourth.

As pointed out in a comment, approach via a straight line will ultimately put you outside of the two regions in which $f$ is not zero. To see this, let $y=g(x)=x^2$.

The secant line through $(0,g(0))$ and $(x_0,g(x_0))$ of $y=x^2$ at some $x_o$ can be made arbitrarily flat by making $|x_o|$ very small, for the slope of the secant line is $x_0$. But your line of approach has a fixed slope. The curve $y=x^2$ is always below any such secant line, near the origin.

So eventually, during your approach, you will stay above the parabola $y=x^2$.